# How to reset data.stackexchange.com cache

Tags: support, data-explorer

When I run any query on data.stackexchange.com, it shows old data. In says xx rows returned in xx ms (**cached**).

The cached data is old one. How to reset/remove this caching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is now updated weekly, on Sunday, at approximately 5 a.m UTC.

When this happens, all of the query result caches are cleared, so you very rarely have to worry that you're getting incorrect results because of caching* as opposed to the data being slightly aged.

<sub>*There's a very specific edge case where this isn't true, but no one's come up with a good reason to be concerned about it so far, so you shouldn't be either.</sub>